# How to handle an iPhone alert with 2 buttons (want to click the non default button)

Tags: javascript, iphone, cocoa-touch, automation

I am automating an iPhone appplication
 While I type the mail ID in the **TO:** field and click on send, I get a confirmation alert with two buttons
 "Cancel" & "Send".
The default button is "cancel". I'm unable to click on the send button. 
 Here is the code snippet which I have used. Please help me with this

//Get the handles

```
window = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow();

target = UIATarget.localTarget();

app = target.frontMostApp();

buttons = window.buttons();

target.delay(2);
```

//tap the send button on the navigation bar

```
app.navigationBar().buttons()["Send"].tap(); 

target.delay(2);
```

//Alert handler

```
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert)

{
   //Unable to enter this portion of the code

   target.delay(2);

   var alerttitle = alert.name();

   UIALogger.logMessage("Alert with title: '"+alerttitle+"' encountered! ");
}
```

The control is not going inside the handler at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a temporary work around which I suppose is not the best approach, but can keep the process going forward

Solution: to tap on the "Send" button using the approximate coordinates of the button relative to the screen.

I have used the following way to achieve that.

```
//Get the handles

window = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow();

target = UIATarget.localTarget();

app = target.frontMostApp();

//Get the handle for the alert

var alertHandle = app.alert();

//Do a log Element tree for the alert to get the coordinates, height and width of the alert

alertHandle.logElementTree();

//Decide the coordinates of the point based on the value of the alert coordinates

target.tap({x:50,y:150});
```

Comment: when I use this approach, its just dismissing the alert. If I tap on "Yes" or "No", it just dismisses the alert. But after dismissing, "Yes" has to do different task, "No" has to do different task. Is there a better way to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

@kiran - When we print the logElementTree the buttons are shown with the name or null. In your case if you are not able to click on button with name , you can do it by referring in form of array. As all elements on screen are picked in form of array.

In general buttons on screen are arranged in form of array starting from 0 and so on upto number of buttons. In your case u can refer to send button as button[0] or any other index which you have to check on your side.

Comment: thanks for the reply dude. Yes i agree with you and I was able to figure it out. The funda in that was to use **UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().alert().buttons()[Buttonname].tap()**  U can also use **UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().alert().buttons()[ButtonIndex].tap()**

Comment: i read ur one more qt to relaunch the app with javascript. I am also currently working on same thing. Can you help me regarding that. DeactivateAppForDuration relaunches it again from same point. But i want to relaunch it from start.

Comment: are u using Instruments for automation ?

Comment: if so, its very unfortunate that there is no way to relaunch it man :( That's a limitation from Apple.

Comment: @kiran yes i am using the instruments. It looks like you have done lots of work on it. Have you ever tried to pause the .js which is being imported to the script which we run in instruments ?

Comment: ha ha .. not so much though, but yes quite a bit of it. U can pause the script (u v the pause button in left top corner). But u can't do it through script. :)

Comment: what do u work on basically ? i mean wat application are u automating ?

Answer (score -2):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message: @"some text"
                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

[alert show];

[alert release];


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
        return;


}
```

using button index you can track which button of alert view was pressed

Comment: By default the Cancel button is pressed when either the script is ended manually / by Instruments. thats because the default alert handler is called which presses the default button (i.e Cancel). But I want to override the default handler and click the "Send" button.

Comment: I am not exactly getting  what you mean to say.How can the button be pressed by default.R u doing it through ur code?

Comment: Nope... I am not doing it through my code. thats where I am perplexed. In the code snippet what I have posted, after I tap on the "Send" button, I get a pop up with two buttons with "cancel" and "send" buttons.<br> buttons = window.buttons();<br> buttons["Send"].tap(); does not work for me. <br> However, for the same application in a different page, I get an alert message with a single OK button. And for that alert <br>buttons["OK"].tap();<br> is working.

Comment: Look try creating the alert the way i posted it in the answer where you want to create two buttons alert

Comment: Hope I could have done it man . But I'm not coding the application, I'm just automating the application using javascript.