# How to handle alert with two buttons in iOS uiautomation

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to signout from an application.It gives me an alert box when I click on 'Logout' -> that has two buttons 'Yes' and 'Cancel' but I am unable to click on the 'Yes' button.I tried the following code :

```
    var log_out = mainWindow.popover().tableViews()[0].cells()["Log out of App"];
    log_out.tap();

    UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert){   
          var name = alert.name();
          UIALogger.logMessage("alert "+name+" encountered");
          if(name == "App") 
          {
              alert.buttons()["Yes"].tap();
              return true;
          } else {
              return false;
          }
      }
```

But the code doesn't even go inside the alert function because it is not printing any message 'alert App encountered'. The script ends after tapping on 'Log out of App' button.              I have gone through these links already -        [How to handle an iPhone alert with 2 buttons (want to click the non default button)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000095/how-to-handle-an-iphone-alert-with-2-buttons-want-to-click-the-non-default-butt) and      [how to select which button to select in alert message for IOS UIAutomation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172937/how-to-select-which-button-to-select-in-alert-message-for-ios-uiautomation) 
but doesn't seem to be working because it is unable to go inside alert only since it is not printing any message through logMessage so not able to use coordinates method also.

Comment: Sounds like your alert handler isn't being called at all, based on your evidence that you never see that log message in the trace log. When are you trying to test this? Is it at the very end of your entire test script? If so, you'll need to put a manual `target.delay(5)` of some kind in there because the automation script engine will end before the alert is fully formed on the screen and your alert callback will never be called. Pausing for a moment before the script finishes will give the time for the script engine to notice the alert and call you back.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to define your onAlert event before.

UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert){ /*code*/}

log_out.tap();